# How do I prevent companies contacting me via stack overflow jobs

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I have recently had a company email me via my stack exchange looking to fill a job vacancy.

All my 'job' settings within my stack overflow profile are set to off: recommended jobs, job alerts, company alerts.

How do I prevent further contact such as this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do you know the email was via stack exchange?  Unless you have an email that you only use on your SE account, and have never shared elsewhere, it is hard to imagine how you would know the source of the email exposure to this company?

Comment: It was SO branded and came from a SO do-not-reply email address. Of course that can be spoofed, but I doubt it

Comment: I'm sending this over to Meta SO since Jobs is an SO-only feature and you'll get better support there.

Comment: Block the no-reply address

Answer (score 10):

Your job status is currently set to "open, but not actively looking" which means you are eligible to appear in the Jobs search database for employers seeking specific skill sets and can be contacted by them. If you no longer wish to appear in that database and don't want to be contacted, you need to change that to "not interested in jobs" in your jobs preferences.